# I want to trigger the discord bot on a specific word in python but can't find the right way

Tags: python, triggers, discord, bots, message

I recently made a discord bot using python for fun but I am unable to find the right way to trigger the bot when the user says a specific word like "rn" because in my code even a word that includes that word inside it like mo*rn*ing triggers the bot. Here's my code:

```
    if "rn"in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send('Really Right now?')
```

Help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a way to do this with regex, but you can do some checks that might solve your problem.
At first, I would suggest checking if there is a space before the rn due to it being used as a word (at least in the cases I can think of).

```
 if " rn" in message.content.lower():
    await message.channel.send('Really Right now?')
```

Another case I can think of is someone just saying "rn" with context to some previously posted message.
In this case, you can check whether the message consists of only "rn" due to them not starting a message with a space.

```
if "rn" == message.content.lower():
    await message.channel.send('Really Right now?')
```

To make matters a bit cleaner you can combine these two to

```
if ("rn" == message.content.lower() or " rn" in message.content.lower()):
    await message.channel.send('Really Right now?')
```

Comment: `if ("rn" == message.content.lower() || " rn" in message.content.lower()):` is a SyntaxError.  Did you mean `if ("rn" == message.content.lower() or " rn" in message.content.lower()):`?

Comment: Thx for the help but I already have some code that works in most cases but not always. Maybe rn isn't such a great example of this let's take "k" if someone sends "kite" my code will still trigger.     ~~~    if message.content.startswith("k") or " k" in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send('Alright')
        return~~~

Comment: You can also get the position of the character 'k' and if there is a character at the position of this + 1 you know it is at the start of a word.

Comment: I m srry i m not great at this stuff could u pls elaborate?